# Using an Animated Gif as Ground Overlays in G. Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, animated-gif

I am currently using Google Maps and would like to use an animated Gif as Overlay in my app.
This is really frustrating as it seems very easy on iOS version of the app, SO I really want to achieve something cool.

The result I would like to see is on 23s of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JI323jA67x0#t=23s

The Ground Overlays seems the bast practice, but doesn't accept animated gif:

```
LatLng NEWARK = new LatLng(40.714086, -74.228697);

GroundOverlayOptions newarkMap = new GroundOverlayOptions()
        .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.newark_nj_1922))
        .position(NEWARK, 8600f, 6500f);

// Add an overlay to the map, retaining a handle to the GroundOverlay object.
GroundOverlay imageOverlay = map.addGroundOverlay(newarkMap);
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/groundoverlay#add_an_overlay

Comment: Thanks for negative vote, can someone explain? Even if my english is not perfect, I think that the question is well explained, with a video of the result, the code I am using as I tried to achieve it.

Comment: What error are you retrieving? What Android version are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a solution, we have decomposed the GIF in multiple images and we are looping all the image list.

We are using the same code as above and everything is fine.

Using an ImageView + Glide as suggested below doesn't help at all as the Image will not move with the Map.

Comment: @ Waza_Be. Can you help me for this problem :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49646431/send-json-to-server-as-string-retrofit

Answer (score 3):

You can use open source library to display Gif image in a single imageview just add its dependency https://github.com/bumptech/glide

and Its easy to use this an example code

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView);
Glide.with(this).load(R.raw.sample_gif).into(imageViewTarget);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, ImageView bounds won't move with Map Move/Tilt/Zoom

Answer (score 0):

@waza_be currently ground overlay does not support animated gif. hopefully they will have it soon. it was possible with version 1 using ImageView and adding it to the map. but in version 2, they scrapped adding views to the map.