# Android GroundoverLay consumes lot of memory

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on Android Weather application where my requirement is to show animated forecast. We have a server from where I load forecast images as Bitmap using Glide and then create GoogleMap's GroundOveryayOption using the bitmap. 
I am using Runnable and Handler for animation.

Everything is working fine except the memory consumption and eventually I got "Out of memory exception"

In-order to smoothly run my forecast animation I have to load all the Bitmaps using Glide and create GroundOverlayOptions obj from Bitmap and store GroundOverlayOptions in HashMap as below.

```
    @Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap bitmap, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                mBitmapLoaded = true;

//the actual image is png and its size is in KBs but Bitmap size is in MBs
                Log.i("Weather", ""+ bitmap.getByteCount());

                GroundOverlayOptions overlayOptions = new GroundOverlayOptions()
                        .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap))
                        .positionFromBounds(getLatLngBounds(mBounds))
                        .visible(frameVisible);

    //groundOverlaysItemMap is a Hashmap to store GroundOverlayOptions where key is Time
                groundOverlaysItemMap.put(mTime, mMap.addGroundOverlay(overlayOptions));
            }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may want to hold only the .png's in memory and have each of them drawn only when needed so that only one of them is in decompressed form at any time. More CPU usage, *much* less RAM usage.

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37000763/1015327

Comment: I need to create GroundOverlayOption object in advance so as not to impact animation as below          
                      
       GroundOverlayOptions overlayOptions = new GroundOverlayOptions()
                        .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap))
                        .positionFromBounds(getLatLngBounds(mBounds))
                        .visible(frameVisible);

Comment: Downsample the images to the lowest resolution that can be tolerated.

Answer (score 1):

Split your "large" image into "small" (e.g. `256x256` pixels) tiles (for example with [MapTiler](https://www.maptiler.com/download/) like in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBNpnG0Us9Q) video), save them into `raw` folder (or device storage) and use [`TileProvider`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileProvider)  like in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14833256/6950238) answer of [Alex Vasilkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687154/alex-vasilkov):

> ```
> public class CustomMapTileProvider implements TileProvider {
>     private static final int TILE_WIDTH = 256;
>     private static final int TILE_HEIGHT = 256;
>     private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 16 * 1024;
>
>     private AssetManager mAssets;
>
>     public CustomMapTileProvider(AssetManager assets) {
>         mAssets = assets;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public Tile getTile(int x, int y, int zoom) {
>         byte[] image = readTileImage(x, y, zoom);
>         return image == null ? null : new Tile(TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT, image);
>     }
>
>     private byte[] readTileImage(int x, int y, int zoom) {
>         InputStream in = null;
>         ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = null;
>
>         try {
>             in = mAssets.open(getTileFilename(x, y, zoom));
>             buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>
>             int nRead;
>             byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
>
>             while ((nRead = in.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
>                 buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
>             }
>             buffer.flush();
>
>             return buffer.toByteArray();
>         } catch (IOException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>             return null;
>         } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>             return null;
>         } finally {
>             if (in != null) try { in.close(); } catch (Exception ignored) {}
>             if (buffer != null) try { buffer.close(); } catch (Exception ignored) {}
>         }
>     }
>
>     private String getTileFilename(int x, int y, int zoom) {
>         return "map/" + zoom + '/' + x + '/' + y + ".png";
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: My requirement is to use GroundOverlay not TileOverlay.

Comment: There are 2 possibilities to reduce memory consumption: 1) split large image to small pieces (tiles) 2) downsample image. `TileOverlay` is almost `GroundOverlay`, but splitted for pieces for best performance and avoiding consumes lot of memory. Other way is downsample the images to the lowest resolution like [JimmyB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1015327/jimmyb) proposed. Also, you can use [`android:largeHeap="true"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap) to request a larger heap size, but it's not good solution.